# ¿Por qué me imprime el 0.10 de primero si es menor que 0.9? pandas

Tags: python, pandas

¿Por qué en el resultado me está imprimiendo que 0.945159 es menor que 0.10? no entiendo.

```
array = {"id":[1,2,3,4,5],"xs":[0.69962398,0.7788454,0.835658,0.945159,0.10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(array)

df = df.sort_values(['id','xs'],ascending=False)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al pasar `['id', 'xs']` como parámetro estás pidiendo que ordene **primero** por id, y en caso de empate, por xs. Así que te ordenará los id de forma desdencente y el id 5 (el mayor) es el que tiene el valor 0.10.

```
>>> df.sort_values(['id','xs'],ascending=False)
   id        xs
4   5  0.100000
3   4  0.945159
2   3  0.835658
1   2  0.778845
0   1  0.699624
```

Si quieres ordenar por xs, obviamente no debes pedirle que ordene antes por id:

```
>>> df.sort_values('xs',ascending=False)
   id        xs
3   4  0.945159
2   3  0.835658
1   2  0.778845
0   1  0.699624
4   5  0.100000
```

Comment: Ahh o sea lo que hace esa función es revertir las posiciones? 
¿cómo hago para que busque los mayores y los ponga de primero? 

¿cómo hago para que busque los menores y los ponga de primero?

Comment: No, lo que hace `sort_values()` es devolverte otro dataframe ordenado por la columna que le pidas. Como ves en mi segundo ejemplo al pedirle que la columna sea 'xs' , los datos aparecen en el orden en que pides. El mayor es el primero y el menor el último. Pero si le pides que ordene según la columna `id` entonces los daatos que encuentra son 1,2,3,4,5 y por tanto el mayor es el 5, y esa fila sería la que quedaría la primera

Comment: Sí ya te entendí esa parte bro, qué otra función puedo utilizar para que agarre los numeros de los campos y los ordene? veo que sort_values() no me sirve para lo que busco

Comment: Pues entonces tienes que explicar mejor qué buscas, porque lo que dices "que agarre los números de los campos y los ordene" es exactamente lo que hace `sort_values()`. Quizás si pones un ejemplo de qué salida querrías obtener...

Comment: Ah bueno muchas gracias